# Manifest validation fails when I try to add 'Extensions' to the App element

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, manifest

I have been trying to connect and authenticate my application to facebook but it's shows a failure message when I am trying to add Extensions element to it. The error message says,

*"Manifest validation fails: Exception: The element 'App' has invalid child element 'Extensions'. List of possible elements expected: 'IconPath'.*"

Though it is clearly narrated in the tutorial, 
http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/config/.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: It is a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application.

Comment: It should be under Deployment > App section.Otherwise it'll prompt a warning.Did you check that ?

Answer (score 0):

Post it after `<tokens></tokens>` tag, this works for me

```
<Tokens>...</Tokens>
<Extensions>
   <Protocol Name="fb<your app id>" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
   <Protocol Name="msft-<your guid as configured on Facebook portal>" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```